# Post large string to Web API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I have a following controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
   public string LoadData(string currentState)
   {

   }
}
```

I post some data from browser with `jQuery.post`. The length of the state should be 29915 characters, but `currentState` variable has only 21621 characters. The end of the string is lost.
I checked if browser sends all data to the server and it does. So the problem somewhere on the server.

Comment: What do you set the content-type?

Comment: Firebug shows the request `Content-Type` header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: I just tested with 30K and worked fine. Does your string contains non-encoded stuff?

Comment: No, it is a valid JSON string. If I send that data directly to the generic handler (*.ashx), it work and I can deserialize the string.

Comment: valid JSON?! This is supposed to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not JSON. do you have `field=value&field=value`?

Comment: yes! it looks like productid=605&state=%7B%22CurVOI%22%3A-1%2C%22CurLI%22%3A-1%2C%22RgbCP%22%3Anull%2C%22CmykCP%22%3Anull%2C%22GrayscaleCP%22%3Anull%2C%22WW%22%3A318.0952%2C%22WH... long encoded string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10332/discussion-between-andrey-m-and-aliostad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `ReadBufferSize` helps:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter.ReadBufferSize = 256 * 1024; // 256 KB
}
```