# ASP.NET Web API does not allow Lengthy base64 URI

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to receive a lengthy base64 string from my Android Client and then decode it to a bitmap in my Web API Project to be uploaded as an image to an Azure BLOB Storage. However, the project returns this message and refuses to take in the parameters:

> **Request URL Too Long**
>
> HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

Obviously the base64 string is very long. How do I get around this and accept the parameters? I've looked around stack for a similar question but none of the answers clearly state ho to fix it in a Web API. Thank you!

Here's a code snippet from my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/addnewpost")]
public IHttpActionResult AddNewMediaActivity(string base64String, string caption, string email, string type)
{
            byte[] f = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            //more code........
}
```

**My Client code on Android:**

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
String message;

HttpPost p = new HttpPost("http://mymobileaddress.azure-mobile.net/api/addactivity?base64String=" + image + "&caption=" + caption + "&email=" + email + "&type=" + type );
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
try {
            object.put("base64String", image);
            object.put("email", image);
            object.put("base64String", image);

} catch (Exception ex) {

}

try {
           message = object.toString();

            p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
            p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            p.setHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json");
            p.setHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", mobileServiceAppId);
            HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);
            if (resp != null) {
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                {

                }
            }

            Log.d("ER", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10279071/1129995

Comment: @Zaki No luck. Doesnt work :(

Comment: normal way is to post data via body .... not via url ...

Comment: @Selvin Please explain, I'm a bit behind with this stuff and I'm not aware of it :(

Comment: hmmm it's all in thousands examples over the internet ... search for FromBody attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data can be either transmitted in the URL of a request, or in the body. You are currently transmitting the data in the URL. And the URL is only allowed to be a finite length. Instead, put your base64 string in the body. See [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

By default, simple parameters like strings are pulled from the URI. To force Web API to look for it in the body, we add a `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/addnewpost")]
public IHttpActionResult AddNewMediaActivity(string caption, string email,
    string type, [FromBody] string base64String)
{
    byte[] f = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    //more code........
}
```

And change your Android client code to put the base64 string in the body, not the URL. It's been a while since I've touched Java and I don't know what library you're using, but I imagine when you're building your HTTP request that you'll have the option of adding some data to the body of the request.

Comment: Ahh man your answer looks like the real deal but I'm having difficulty finding a way to post base64 through the body in my client. I'll accept this, however if you know of a way to post the base64 string in android, do let me know :)

Comment: @Earthling I'd need to know what Java library you're using to send the HTTP Request.

Comment: I'm using the apache HttpClient, mate

Comment: @Earthling [This HttpClient](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/tree/trunk/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/client)? Please edit the relevant Android code that generates the HTTP POST request into your question. Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java) help?

Answer (score 1):

(I have deleted the other one, I want to keep this one because the issue was using asp.net 5 beta 8 and is more recent)

I had this issue recently and the parameter was moved to receive a byte[] (byte array) From Body

First I tried from body and the string was received but the string was truncated and the file can't be recreated in the server side.

In my application the base64 came from a conversion of an array buffer created from an input file.

The base64 is sent in a json from angular.